# RxJava - не пойму как обернуть метод из Dao в Single в Репозитории

Tags: java, android, rxjava, android-room

In Dao:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM person_table WHERE status = :status_debil ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5")
    List<Person> getFivePersonsFrom(String status_debil);
```

In Repo:

```
public class PersonRepository {
//variables declared

    PersonRepository(Application application) {
        PersonRoomDatabase db = PersonRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);
    //variables initialized
    }

//Methods
}
```

Что и где мне нужно написать в Repository, чтобы правильно получаемый List обернуть в Single
и затем мочь дернуть метод из ViewModel указав нужные потоки?

Comment: Сменить возвращаемое значение в Dao на `Singe<List<Person>>`?

Comment: а что писать в репозитории?

Comment: Сильно зависит от того, что вы хотите получить. Возможно, там надо написать тоже самое что и в Dao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятен вопрос - в простейшем случае:
In Dao:

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM person_table WHERE status = :status_genius ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5")
    Singe<List<Person>> getFivePersonsFrom(String status_genius);
```

In Repo:

```
public class PersonRepository {
//variables declared
    private PersonDao mDao;

    PersonRepository(Application application) {
        PersonRoomDatabase db = PersonRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);
        mDao = db.getPersonDao();
    //variables initialized
    }

//Methods
    public Singe<List<Person>> getFivePersonsFrom(String status_genius) {
        return mDao.getFivePersonsFrom(status_genius);
    }
}
```